# bsc get transaction list by address Web3 (realtime,socket)

Tags: web3js, nodejs, bsc

How can I track transactions of a wallet in the bsc network instantly? (I am thinking of using web3 js.)

I don't want to do it with the api on BSCscan. As far as I know, it does not show it instantly.